# How can I remove only consecutive duplicate fields when the id is not consecutive in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In this table, I have a price change history.  The prices are checked regularly and as you can see, sometimes the price does not change.  How can I take a specific sku and delete all cases where a duplicate price is consecutively measured.  As you can see, on 08-08, the price changed to 79.47.  Then, it stayed that way until 08-11 when it changed to 79.41.  I don't need all the repeated 79.47 since I can just assume that the price didn't change.  So, I just need each point in time that the price changed, and that will allow me to save a lot of space.

```
╔══════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║    id    ║  sku   ║ amount ║        date         ║
╠══════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║   225200 ║ 388744 ║ 60     ║ 2014-08-02 22:08:18 ║
║  1571656 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-06 20:53:36 ║
║  1572002 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-06 20:53:42 ║
║  2092567 ║ 388744 ║ 79.45  ║ 2014-08-07 01:22:13 ║
║  2608362 ║ 388744 ║ 79.44  ║ 2014-08-07 05:50:45 ║
║  4403138 ║ 388744 ║ 79.44  ║ 2014-08-07 18:59:02 ║
║  4935625 ║ 388744 ║ 79.44  ║ 2014-08-07 23:18:56 ║
║  5356014 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-08 03:41:30 ║
║  5703764 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-08 08:00:47 ║
║  8559295 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-09 22:40:42 ║
║  8878123 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-10 02:54:05 ║
║  9204053 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-10 07:13:06 ║
║  9538507 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-10 11:27:51 ║
║  9863478 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-10 15:44:34 ║
║ 10184051 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-10 20:02:29 ║
║ 10503334 ║ 388744 ║ 79.41  ║ 2014-08-11 00:18:44 ║
║ 10821782 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 04:34:22 ║
║ 11135386 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 08:52:31 ║
║ 11446160 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 13:07:56 ║
║ 11760103 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 17:26:09 ║
║ 12074366 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 21:42:37 ║
║ 12399508 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 02:13:05 ║
║ 12726720 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 06:45:28 ║
║ 12726970 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 06:45:37 ║
║ 13059695 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 11:16:35 ║
║ 13406731 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 15:53:01 ║
║ 13750598 ║ 388744 ║ 79.48  ║ 2014-08-12 20:24:4  ║
╚══════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

So, after the query, it would hopefully look like this:

```
    ╔══════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
    ║    id    ║  sku   ║ amount ║        date         ║
    ╠══════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
    ║   225200 ║ 388744 ║ 60     ║ 2014-08-02 22:08:18 ║
    ║  1571656 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-06 20:53:36 ║
    ║  2092567 ║ 388744 ║ 79.45  ║ 2014-08-07 01:22:13 ║
    ║  2608362 ║ 388744 ║ 79.44  ║ 2014-08-07 05:50:45 ║
    ║  5356014 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-08 03:41:30 ║
    ║ 10503334 ║ 388744 ║ 79.41  ║ 2014-08-11 00:18:44 ║
    ║ 10821782 ║ 388744 ║ 79.33  ║ 2014-08-11 04:34:22 ║
    ║ 12399508 ║ 388744 ║ 79.47  ║ 2014-08-12 02:13:05 ║
    ║ 13750598 ║ 388744 ║ 79.48  ║ 2014-08-12 20:24:4  ║
    ╚══════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Is `id` column sequential ?

Comment: No, it is not, as you can see in the sample.

Comment: It looks sequential in both examples...

Comment: @gmsantos I think OP means it is sequential but non-consecutive.

Comment: Ah yes, exactly.  Sequential but non-consecutive.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job :

```
SELECT
  ph1.sku, 
  ph1.id as ph1Id, 
  ph2.id as ph2Id, 
  ph1.histDate,
  ph2.amount as oldAmount, 
  ph1.amount as newAmount 
FROM priceHistory as ph1 
LEFT JOIN priceHistory as ph2 ON
ph2.id = 
(SELECT max(id) FROM priceHistory AS ph3 WHERE ph3.id < ph1.id and ph1.SKU = ph3.SKU)
WHERE ph1.amount <> ph2.amount OR 
      ph2.amount is null
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b22710/18).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what this is doing?  What is the oldAmount and newAmount?  and the two ids as well?

Comment: oldAmount is the amount before the change and newAmount is the amount after the change.  You can remove oldAmount and the ph1.id and ph2.id if you want.  Have a look at the SQL Fiddle provided.

Answer (score 0):

## PROPOSED SOLUTION

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
CREATE TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys SELECT id FROM priceHistory LIMIT 0;
ALTER TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
SET @curr_amount = 0;
INSERT INTO priceHistory_DeleteKeys
SELECT id FROM (SELECT ZapKey,id,amount
FROM (SELECT (@ZapKey := IF(@curr_amount=amount,1,0)) ZapKey,
id,amount,(@curr_amount := amount) FROM priceHistory
WHERE sku=388744 ORDER BY id) AA) A WHERE ZapKey=1;
DELETE B.* FROM priceHistory_DeleteKeys A INNER JOIN priceHistory B USING (id);
DROP TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
```

## PROPOSED SOLUTION EXPLAINED

Create a temp table for the id values to delete

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
CREATE TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys SELECT id FROM priceHistory LIMIT 0;
ALTER TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Collect the id values of the rows to delete without a join into a temp table.

```
SET @curr_amount = 0;
INSERT INTO priceHistory_DeleteKeys
SELECT id FROM (SELECT ZapKey,id,amount
FROM (SELECT (@ZapKey := IF(@curr_amount=amount,1,0)) ZapKey,
id,amount,(@curr_amount := amount) FROM priceHistory
WHERE sku=388744 ORDER BY id) AA) A WHERE ZapKey=1;
```

Then, perform a DELETE JOIN between priceHistory and the temp table.

```
DELETE B.* FROM priceHistory_DeleteKeys A INNER JOIN priceHistory B USING (id);
```

Then, drop the temp table

```
DROP TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
mysql> select * from priceHistory;
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id       | sku    | amount | histDate            |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|   225200 | 388744 |  60.00 | 2014-08-02 22:08:18 |
|  1571656 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-06 20:53:36 |
|  1572002 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-06 20:53:42 |
|  2092567 | 388744 |  79.45 | 2014-08-07 01:22:13 |
|  2608362 | 388744 |  79.44 | 2014-08-07 05:50:45 |
|  4403138 | 388744 |  79.44 | 2014-08-07 18:59:02 |
|  4935625 | 388744 |  79.44 | 2014-08-07 23:18:56 |
|  5356014 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-08 03:41:30 |
|  5703764 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-08 08:00:47 |
|  8559295 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-09 22:40:42 |
|  8878123 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-10 02:54:05 |
|  9204053 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-10 07:13:06 |
|  9538507 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-10 11:27:51 |
|  9863478 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-10 15:44:34 |
| 10184051 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-10 20:02:29 |
| 10503334 | 388744 |  79.41 | 2014-08-11 00:18:44 |
| 10821782 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 04:34:22 |
| 11135386 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 08:52:31 |
| 11446160 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 13:07:56 |
| 11760103 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 17:26:09 |
| 12074366 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 21:42:37 |
| 12399508 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 02:13:05 |
| 12726720 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 06:45:28 |
| 12726970 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 06:45:37 |
| 13059695 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 11:16:35 |
| 13406731 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 15:53:01 |
| 13750598 | 388744 |  79.48 | 2014-08-12 20:24:40 |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
27 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

## PROPOSED SOLUTION EXECUTED

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys SELECT id FROM priceHistory LIMIT 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SET @curr_amount = 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO priceHistory_DeleteKeys
    -> SELECT id FROM (SELECT ZapKey,id,amount
    -> FROM (SELECT (@ZapKey := IF(@curr_amount=amount,1,0)) ZapKey,
    -> id,amount,(@curr_amount := amount) FROM priceHistory
    -> WHERE sku=388744 ORDER BY id) AA) A WHERE ZapKey=1;
Query OK, 18 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 18  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> DELETE B.* FROM priceHistory_DeleteKeys A INNER JOIN priceHistory B USING (id);
Query OK, 18 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE priceHistory_DeleteKeys;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

## SAMPLE DATA AFTER DELETE

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM priceHistory;
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| id       | sku    | amount | histDate            |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|   225200 | 388744 |  60.00 | 2014-08-02 22:08:18 |
|  1571656 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-06 20:53:36 |
|  2092567 | 388744 |  79.45 | 2014-08-07 01:22:13 |
|  2608362 | 388744 |  79.44 | 2014-08-07 05:50:45 |
|  5356014 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-08 03:41:30 |
| 10503334 | 388744 |  79.41 | 2014-08-11 00:18:44 |
| 10821782 | 388744 |  79.33 | 2014-08-11 04:34:22 |
| 12399508 | 388744 |  79.47 | 2014-08-12 02:13:05 |
| 13750598 | 388744 |  79.48 | 2014-08-12 20:24:40 |
+----------+--------+--------+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Answer (score -1):

```
drop table if exists  #yourtable --Give it a go, it is safe to copy paste and run it
create table #yourtable
(
    id bigint
    ,sku int 
    ,amount float
    ,_date datetime
)
insert into #yourtable
values  (225200,388744,60   ,'2014-08-02 22:08:18')
,( 1571656,388744,79.47,'2014-08-06 20:53:36'     )
,( 1572002,388744,79.47,'2014-08-06 20:53:42'     )
,( 2092567,388744,79.45,'2014-08-07 01:22:13'     )
,( 2608362,388744,79.44,'2014-08-07 05:50:45'     )
,( 4403138,388744,79.44,'2014-08-07 18:59:02'     )
,( 4935625,388744,79.44,'2014-08-07 23:18:56'     )
,( 5356014,388744,79.47,'2014-08-08 03:41:30'     )
,( 5703764,388744,79.47,'2014-08-08 08:00:47'     )
,( 8559295,388744,79.47,'2014-08-09 22:40:42'     )
,( 8878123,388744,79.47,'2014-08-10 02:54:05'     )
,( 9204053,388744,79.47,'2014-08-10 07:13:06'     )
,( 9538507,388744,79.47,'2014-08-10 11:27:51'     )
,( 9863478,388744,79.47,'2014-08-10 15:44:34'     )
,(10184051,388744,79.47,'2014-08-10 20:02:29'     )
,(10503334,388744,79.41,'2014-08-11 00:18:44'     )
,(10821782,388744,79.33,'2014-08-11 04:34:22'     )
,(11135386,388744,79.33,'2014-08-11 08:52:31'     )
,(11446160,388744,79.33,'2014-08-11 13:07:56'     )
,(11760103,388744,79.33,'2014-08-11 17:26:09'     )
,(12074366,388744,79.33,'2014-08-11 21:42:37'     )
,(12399508,388744,79.47,'2014-08-12 02:13:05'     )
,(12726720,388744,79.47,'2014-08-12 06:45:28'     )
,(12726970,388744,79.47,'2014-08-12 06:45:37'     )
,(13059695,388744,79.47,'2014-08-12 11:16:35'     )
,(13406731,388744,79.47,'2014-08-12 15:53:01'     )
,(13750598,388744,79.48,'2014-08-12 20:24:40'     )

;with RowsWithLag AS
(
    select 
        y.*
        ,lag(y.sku,1)over(order by y._date, y.id) as lagSku
        ,lag(y.amount,1)over(order by y._date, y.id) as lagAmount
    from #yourtable y
)
delete rwl
from RowsWithLag rwl
where rwl.sku = rwl.lagSku
and rwl.amount = rwl.lagAmount

select *
from #yourtable
```

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote without even commenting why.

Comment: oh. Sorry. My answer is in SQL Server version 2012 onwards... My bad! :P